# django crispy forms {{ field.value }}

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I think that my question is pretty simple for somebody who solved this issues already working with crispy forms.

I want to have dynamic url basing on one filed.value.

```
HTML('<a class="btn btn-warning" href="https://my.custom.url{{ field.value }}">Edit</a>')
```

Not sure why but {{ filed.value }} is empty for me.

Thanks,

Jakub

Comment: Where is `field.value` coming from? Is it a field in your form?

Comment: Yes in my form and model

Answer (score 1):

Ekhm answer is very simple: Need to use {{ form.formhub_id.value }}